# NASM assembler infinite loop with cx register

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls

```
section .data:
         msg1: db "Hello 10 times!"
         msglen1: equ $-msg1
section .text:
        global _initial:
        global _start:
        global _end:
_initial:
        mov cx,10
_start:
        dec cx
        mov ecx,msg1
        mov edx,msglen1
        mov eax,4
        int 80h
        cmp cx,0 
        jz _end
        jmp _start
_end
        mov eax,1
        int 80h
```

Above code had to be produce "Hello 10 times" 10 times.But it getting go into infinite loop,and i couldn't understand why ?
i think cx register doesn't decrease or whatever else ?

Comment: Sorry i couldn't understand,are you trying to say that i should change cx from cx to esi ? İ've tried just now,but infinite loop come out again.Maybe that's because i am beginner in assembly but i wan't to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of problems.

- The default entry point for a Linux program is `_start`. Your program starts by executing at label `_start` not at `initial` so your loop counter isn't being initialized.
- Section names do not have a `:` on the name, and neither do labels for the `global`<sup>1</sup>
- You are missing a parameter for the `SYS_Write` system call. The 32-bit system calls are [documented in a table](https://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/):

  [image]

  You need to set *EBX* to a file descriptor. STDIN=0, STDOUT = 1, STDERR=2. You want to write to the console so you need to set *EBX* to 1 before calling `Int 80h`
- You are clobbering one of the parameters (*ECX*) to the `SYS_Write` system call. *CX* and *ECX* are part of the same register. *CX* is the lower 16-bits of *ECX*. Changing *CX* changes *ECX*. You need to use some other register for the loop counter. *ESI*, *EDI*, and *EBP* are currently unused in your code. Change all occurrences of *CX* to the 32-bit register *ESI*.

Your code could look like:

```
section .data
        msg1: db "Hello 10 times!", 10
                               ; Add 10 on the end of the string for Line Feed
                               ;     so each message prints on separate line
        msglen1 equ $-msg1

section .text
        global _initial
        global _start
        global _end

_start:
        mov esi, 10            ; Initialize loop counter
_msgloop:
        dec esi                ; Decrement loop counter
        mov ebx, 1             ; File Descriptor 1 = Write to Standard Output (STDOUT)
        mov ecx, msg1          ; Address of message to print
        mov edx, msglen1       ; Length of message to print
        mov eax, 4             ; SYS_Write system call = 4
        int 80h
        cmp esi, 0             ; Has the loop counter reached 0?
        jz _end                ; If it has then we are done
        jmp _msgloop           ; otherwise go back and print message again
_end:
        mov eax,1              ; SYS_Exit system call
        int 80h
```

You could have rewritten your loop this way:

```
section .data
        msg1: db "Hello 10 times!", 10
                               ; Add 10 on the end of the string for Line Feed
                               ;     so each message prints on separate line
        msglen1 equ $-msg1

section .text
        global _start

_start:
        mov esi, 10            ; Initialize loop counter

.msgloop:
        mov ebx, 1             ; File Descriptor 1 = Write to Standard Output (STDOUT)
        mov ecx, msg1          ; Address of message to print
        mov edx, msglen1       ; Length of message to print
        mov eax, 4             ; SYS_Write system call = 4
        int 80h
        dec esi                ; Decrement loop counter
        jnz .msgloop           ; If loop counter hasn't reached zero then print again

        mov eax,1              ; SYS_Exit system call
        int 80h
```

---

### Footnotes:

- <sup>1</sup>You don't need to make `initial` and `end` global since you aren't linking to any other object files. Those `global` lines can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use the `cx` register for your loop count, while needing to use `ecx` as a parameter for your output.  Since `cx` is the lower 16 bits of `ecx`, you clobber your loop count.

You need to either use some other register (that is not used during the system call) for you loop count, or store the count in a local variable on the stack.

Comment: i've already used ecx,edx and eax registers,i don't know which register can i use for that.İ tried use ebx register just now but this time nothing in output.

Comment: @MichaelPetch İ also tried what you said,but at this time there's nothing in output,no error,no anything,terminal cursor is waiting.İ got lost myself in x86 assembly.

Comment: @ShooterLensAim: you need `ebx=1` as the file descriptor for `write(1, msg, msglen)`.  Or EBX=0 happens to work, too.  [ebx register doesn't work in NASM but ecx work](//stackoverflow.com/a/57374867)  Use ESI, EDI, or EBP, and read the docs about Linux system-call calling conventions and the system call you're using.